# How to put QWindow into QWidget's layout (Qt5)

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qt5

I want to insert QQuickView to my old qt4 application in some widget layout. How to mix QWidget and QWindow in a single application?

Are there any examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed in Qt 5.1. Citing [1]

> To remedy this problem, Qt 5.1 introduces the function **QWidget::createWindowContainer()**. A function that creates a QWidget wrapper for an existing QWindow, allowing it to live inside a QWidget-based application. Using QQuickView or QOpenGLContext together with widgets is now possible.

[1] https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer

Comment: the [1] link is broken, the new url is https://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/

Answer (score 2):

Found [this issue](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-25643) on Qt-project bugtracker.

There is some workarounds in comments.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...